# Maui dynamic text won't update on the phone

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

So I have written a Maui app.  It all works on the emulator.  I have 20 questions, which can change, so I have one page, where I keep dynamically setting the text of the question.  This does not work on a phone, no questions ever appear.  I've found a few answers as to why and I've done this:

```cs
internal class QuestionViewModel : ObservableViewModelBase
{
    public string Question
    {
        get => _question;
        set => SetProperty(ref _question, value);
    }
    private string _question;
}
```

Where `ObservableViewModelBase` wraps some generic property stuff and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Then:

```cs
QuestionViewModel = new QuestionViewModel();
BindingContext = QuestionViewModel;
```

and

```xml
Text="{Binding Question}"
```

Then I do this:

```cs
QuestionViewModel.Question = newQuestion;
Application.Current.MainPage.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => QuestionViewModel.Question = newQuestion);
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    QuestionViewModel.Question = newQuestion;
});
```

Where the first one just works in the emulator and both of the others were suggested to fix my issue.  The client ignored my requests to test on phone (they still haven't) so I'm basically at the point of delivering and this is killing me.  Any suggestions welcome.

So I've moved to using a binding and a view model (although I have only one dynamic property) and called methods that are supposed to get the main thread to update the UI. But it is not.  Thanks.

*edit* I found this:

```cs
this.InvalidateMeasure();
```

and it does literally nothing.  So now I've actually refreshed the UI in code and nothing works.

Edit in response to questions.  This is the full XAML of the control

```
<Label x:Name="question"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
               Text="{Binding Question}"
               Margin="20, 0"
               Grid.Row="1"
               FontSize="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

I am testing on a Pixel 5.  I am using the Pixel 5 emulator  This is not a rare phone, if it works on other phones that's not going to be good enough.  This works on the emulator, there are no issues with text colour, etc.

The basic UI is there's a grid to control layout and a few controls with their columns and rows specified.  I am thinking of making it a list with an ObservableList that only ever shows one item

Comment: Can you please show more of the code, especially the XAML where you're binding to the `Question` property as well as where the property of the ViewModel is updated? BTW, you don't need to set the property on the main thread. Setting it like `QuestionViewModel.Question = newQuestion;` is sufficient.

Comment: 1. Show the complete xaml element that contains `Text="{Binding Question}"`. 2. Maybe device has different background color, so text is invisible (e.g. white on white)? 3. Is that inside of a `DataTemplate`? 4. *"The client ignored my requests to test on phone (they still haven't)"* - are you saying that you aren't able to test on a similar phone? what model phone? Do you have access to any phone by the same manufacturer? Are you able to see it work on a phone by a different vendor?

Comment: I can show the full XAML.  To restate, this works perfectly in the emulator, in all guises.  The colours and so on are fine.  I am testing on my phone, I am saying the client is as yet not testing on a phone at all.  I use the Pixel 5 emulator and have a pixel 5.  It's a common enough phone that this is an issue no matter what

Comment: Update - thanks for the suggestion, I removed all attributes and it works.  It fails when I specify the row it should be on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for putting me on the right track.  I removed all attributes and added them progressively.  The text showed until I put it inside the grid, then it seems the grid defaulted the foreground colour to be the background colour.  Once I specified a text colour (in the emulator it always defaults to black) it started to work.  I assume the bit where I moved to MVVM was required either way.